# Search for multiline regex

Tags: regex, emacs, multiline

I have several source file which have function definitions as follows.

```
ReturnType ClassName::
FunctionName(FunctionArgs...)
{
 ....
}

ReturnType ClassName::NestedClassName::
FunctionName(FunctionArgs...)
{
 ....
}
```

I want to grep through the files and list all the functions of first type sepeartely and second type separately. Is there a way to do it in emacs?
Note: I have tried C-q C-j from [https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9548/what-is-regex-to-match-newline-character]. it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be two inter-related pieces to this: the regexps to use, and the search method.  I am making the following assumptions (sorry for not clarifying these beforehand; I don't have enough rep to comment):

1. You are interested in collecting just the function signature (the first two lines), not what's inside the braces.
2. Colons never appear in return types or class names.
3. No line ever ends in a double colon inside a function body.

Within Emacs, I can distinguish the two cases with the regexps

```
^[^:]+::\n.+$
^[^:]+::[^:]+::\n.+$
```

(where you would replace `\n` with an actual newline (via C-q C-j, for instance) in an interactive usage).

If you have all of the buffers opened in Emacs, you can just use `multi-occur` now.  Otherwise, you can call out to grep using the `grep` command, or just use M-! to call grep directly.

If you're using grep, then you need a different approach (or at least I couldn't find an appropriate regexp).  If you drop the second line and use the `-A 1` switch (which tells grep to print the line following each match), everything seems to work properly.  You also need to escape the + operator, for some reason.  Here are the resulting commands:

```
grep -A 1 "^[^:]\+::$" files
grep -A 1 "^[^:]\+::[^:]\+::$" files
```